# SyntaxError: function statement requires a name

Tags: javascript, jquery

im confused about this error which i become without todo any event like click etc.
Yes i used the search here, but in all of the cases i found the situation was another problem.

The "SyntaxError: function statement requires a name" was throwing by firebug after a pagerefresh here: `onGoTo:function(evt){`

this is my function:

```
function exampleFc(ctx){
'use strict';

  var goTo = $('a[href*=#]',this.$ctx);
  goTo.on('click',$.proxy(this.onGoTo,this));

 onGoTo:function(evt){
     evt.preventDefault();
     var elem = $(evt.currentTarget).attr('href');

     if(elem.length > 1){
         $('html,body').animate({
             scrollTop: $(elem).offset().top
         }, 700, function (){location.hash = elem;});
     }
     return false;
 }
```

};

whats wrong? i want to call the function onGoTo by catching the click event.

Comment: looks like you're using `this` wrong as well

Answer (score 3):

the syntax is incorrect. that syntax should be used only inside objects.

```
var obj = { onGoTo: function(){ } }
```

in areas other than object you should use this syntax:

```
var onGoTo = function( ) {  }; // function declaration
onGoto() // function call
```

or, in case of your code,

```
  this.onGoTo = function() {}; // function declaration
  this.onGoTo(); // function call
```

finally your code should be like this:

```
function exampleFc(ctx){
    'use strict';

    var goTo = $('a[href*=#]',this.$ctx);
    goTo.on('click',$.proxy(this.onGoTo,this));

    this.onGoTo = function(evt) {
         evt.preventDefault();
         var elem = $(evt.currentTarget).attr('href');

         if(elem.length > 1){
             $('html,body').animate({
                 scrollTop: $(elem).offset().top
             }, 700, function (){location.hash = elem;});
         }
         return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: hmm, ok sounds good. can you show me please how to call the function in your second example please? so i mean how can i call it with my goTo.on('click', ...) part. i cant call here only a var. thanks

Comment: it can be called just like other function. but it should be declared before calling :)

Answer (score 0):

ok, as Prakash GPz already says is the syntax wrong.

My solution to solved it is:

```
function exampleFc(ctx){
'use strict';

var onGoTo = function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    var elem = $(evt.currentTarget).attr('href');

    if(elem.length > 1){
        $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(elem).offset().top
    }, 700, function (){location.hash = elem;});
}
return false;
};

var goTo = $('a[href*=#]',ctx);
goTo.on('click',onGoTo));
```

};

by the way, the function above you can use to scroll anywhere in the DOM.
make sure that the scroll link have a href attribute starts with the #-Symbol and that this id exists.

best

Answer (score 0):

This line cause your error

```
onGoTo:function(evt){
```

Because inside functions you can't use object syntax and have to use `=` instead of `:`

```
var onGoTo = function(evt){
```

Note that proxy object is a part of es6 implementation.